# Por que não consigo ler uma string no console?

Tags: c#, .net, string, console

Estou tentando ler uma *string* digitada no console, que fica na metade do código, mas o que acontece é que ele passa direto e exibe as informações finais.

```
using System;

namespace Viernes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int xDig = -1, yDig = -1;
            char pCardeal = 'N';
           //Verificando a validade

            while (xDig < 0 && yDig < 0)
            {
                Console.Write("Digite as coordenadas \nx: ");
                xDig = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("y: ");
                yDig = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Console.Write("Cardeal 'N' 'S' 'L' 'O': ");
            pCardeal = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
            pCardeal = Char.ToUpper(pCardeal);

            //Comandos
            Console.WriteLine("Digite alguns comandos, 'E'squerda, 'D'ireita, 'A'vançar.");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();

            str = str.ToUpper();
            char[] Comands = str.ToCharArray();

            //Obj
            SpaceCar sp = new SpaceCar(xDig, yDig, pCardeal);

            foreach (var separaLetras in Comands)
            {
                switch (separaLetras)
                {
                    case 'E':
                        sp.girarEsquerda();
                    break;
                    case 'D':
                        sp.girarDireita();
                    break;
                    case 'A':
                        sp.avancarBloco(xDig, yDig);
                    break;
                }
            }
            //Imprimindo Destino
            Console.Write("Coordenadas: {0}{1}{2}", sp.PosicaoX,sp.PosicaoY, sp.PosicaoCardial);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[Código no Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/z7juqFdF)

Complemento da [classe `SpaceCar` em outro PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/Nw7qs6Pt).

Comment: Olá. Porque não edita a sua pergunta e coloca a parte do código relevante na pergunta em vez de colar o link para o pastebin?

Comment: Seu código sequer compila. Onde está a classe SpaceCar? Se ela não é absolutamente necessária para o código, então você poderia tirar ele para postar aqui. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A classe é necessária. Coloquei o código no topo e funciona, mas eu preciso que esta inserção seja feita no meio do código.

Comment: Se nós não pudermos nem testar seu código fica difícil ajudar. Você tem que colocar um código completo, mínimo e verificável. Há outros problemas que fazem seu código nem executar. Seria bom dar mais detalhes de como reproduzir o problema também.

Comment: Segue código do SpaceCar http://pastebin.com/Nw7qs6Pt

Comment: na linha `pCardeal = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());` o método `Read` não fica esperando algo a ser digitado, ele pega o que já foi digitado. Ou você precisa fazer um *loop* para pegar o que ainda vai ser digitado, ou melhor ainda, utilize o `ReadKey(flase)` no lugar, só que aí você vai ter que interpretar o retorno retorno que é da classe `ConsoleKeyInfo`, ou seja retorna a informação da tecla e não do character digitado, precisa de uma "conversão". Se achar muito complicado e o `ReadLine` for suficiente, use ele no lugar. Parece que esta alteração resolve o problema que você pouco descreveu.

Comment: Já havia testado o ReadLine E não funcionou
Console.WriteLine("Digite alguns comandos, 'E'squerda, 'D'ireita, 'A'vançar.");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            str = str.ToUpper();
            char[] Comands = str.ToCharArray();

Comment: Não existe nenhuma razão para o `ReadLine()` não funcionar. Se funcionou nos outros, tem que funcionar neste.

Comment: @Pegasus Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Seu código tem alguns problemas, mas vou só responder a sua dúvida.

Um código exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável poderia ter sido escrito como o exemplo abaixo que demonstra o a solução.

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Convert;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Write("Cardeal 'N' 'S' 'L' 'O': ");
        var pCardeal = char.ToUpper(ToChar(ReadKey(false).Key.ToString()));
        WriteLine($"PosicaoCardinal {pCardeal}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VR3opO). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wN7UfJ). Também [coloquei no GitHub para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Console/ReadKey.cs).

O problema que eu pude entender é que estava usando o método [`Console.Read()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Console_Read) que não fica esperando por uma tecla a ser digitada. Ele pega o caractere que está no *buffer*, provavelmente, do teclado. A solução é usar um [`Console.ReadKey(false)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Console_ReadKey_System_Boolean_) que pega a **tecla** que foi acionada. Por isso é preciso tratar o seu retorno como uma tecla através da estrutura [`ConsoleKeyInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0). Mas é possível tratá-la facilmente com o `ToString()`, como mostrado acima.

Tem um [código parcialmente refatorado e funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BX7u6c). Por problema técnicos dele, não dá para testar corretamente, então testei com o compilador na minha máquina.

De qualquer forma fica esquisito ter duas digitações que espera um <kbd>ENTER</kbd> para terminar a digitação depois uma que não espera e depois outra que espera de novo. Se quiser manter o padrão use logo um `Console.ReadLine()` no lugar do `Console.ReadKey()`. Se você quer ler uma `string`, então leia uma `string`, e isto se faz com `Console.ReadLine()`:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Convert;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Write("Cardeal 'N' 'S' 'L' 'O': ");
        var pCardeal = char.ToUpper(ToChar(ReadLine()));
        WriteLine($"PosicaoCardinal {pCardeal}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YhmLht). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1KgZef). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Console/CharHandling.cs).

Comment: Havia esquecido de colocar Line depois de Read.
'pCardeal = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());'
Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Console.ReadLine()` e não `Console.ReadKey()`